# How to route only local addresses using dnsmasq

Tags: dnsmasq

I'm trying to have the dnsmasq of a server only listen to and respond to queries within a local network using their private IP addresses. All of the hosts needed are already on the /etc/host file, so all I need to do is configure the dnsmasq.conf file so that it only responds to local-only domains.

While researching, I've only found documents for "How to create a DNS/DHCP server using dnsmasq" but not much on routing to only certain IP addresses.

I've tried the instructions from this link:
https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/dnsmasq-easy-lan-name-services/
and it put dnsmasq in a failed state.

When I used listen-address=[private ip] in the dnsmasq.conf file, I did nslookup for the servers that are supposed to be on the private network but it been showing the public ip for the server and address.

Answer (score 1):

You should consult the [official dnsmasq man page](http://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html). In particular the `local-service` and `localise-queries` options:

> `--local-service`
>
> Accept  DNS queries only from hosts whose address is on a local subnet, ie a subnet for which an interface exists on the server. This option only has effect if there are no `--interface`, `--except-interface`, `--listen-address` or `--auth-server` options. It is in              tended to be set as a default on installation, to allow unconfigured installations to be useful but also safe from being used for DNS amplification attacks.

> `-y`, `--localise-queries`
>
> Return  answers  to DNS queries from `/etc/hosts` and `--interface-name` which depend on the interface over which the query was received. If a name has more than one address associated with it, and at least one of those addresses is on the same subnet as the interface to which the query was sent, then return only the address(es) on that subnet. This allows for a server  to have multiple addresses in `/etc/hosts` corresponding to each of its interfaces, and hosts will get the correct address based  on  which  network they are attached to. Currently this facility is limited to IPv4.

The first option `local-service` addresses your first concern, so that `dnsmasq` will only answer queries from hosts on the same subnet. The second option `localise-queries` will return answers with IP addresses from the same subnet if there are multiple IP addresses for a given name known to dnsmasq.